# Windows Media Player Plugin in MAC OS X Safari Browser

Tags: macos, video, safari, activex

My website is using windows media player in playing videos in a web page. It is mandatory to use windows media player because I'm using it in E-learning tracking. However, I got problem in displaying the windows media player using MAC OS X in safari 5.0.4 version of browser. I'm using below tag to load media player in the browser:

Example:

```
<object id="MediaPlayer" width="400" height="365" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
<param name="uiMode" value="full">
<param name="autoStart" value="false">
<param name="stretchToFit" value="true">
<param iname="windowlessVideo" value="true">
</object>
```

Could it be possible to display the media player using MAC OS X in safari 5.0.4 version of browser?

What would be the alternative code to load the windows media player in MAC OS X using safari browser?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting an appropriate type attribute for the object element. [This article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/byebyeembed/) recommends `type="video/x-ms-wmv”` It also contains additional tips that may be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the article. I'm trying to automate the player to be played using javascript but it will not work. example: Mediaplayer.controls.play();

Answer (score 1):

You need [Windows Media® Components for QuickTime (aka Flip4Mac)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=915d874d-d747-4180-a400-5f06b1b5e559) installed on the Mac.

Comment: I've installed the Flip4Mac but the windows media player cannot be displayed in the page. Does the <object> tag cause to not load the player? Thanks for the adivise